# How to see SMART values for Sandisk SDW32G?

Tags: ssd

I have a Asus tablet using a Sandisk EMMC as storage, I want to see the SMART values on it but can't.

It is detected as "Sandisk SDW32G" in Windows task manager, but both HWinfo and Crystaldiskinfo cannot detect the disk.

Which tool can detect it and show the SMART values?

Comment: [Best 7 Free Tools to Check SSD Health and Monitor Performance](http://mashtips.com/ssd-health-test-and-performance-monitor-tools/) includes other tools you can try.

Comment: Unfortunately if it is an eMMC rather than a "proper" SSD then it won't normally support SMART monitoring.